# Convert string to date then format the date

Tags: java, date, format, simpledateformat

I am formatting a string to a date using the code

```
String start_dt = '2011-01-01';

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(start_dt);
```

But how do I convert the date from `YYYY-MM-DD` format to `MM-DD-YYYY` format?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat#format(Date)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String start_dt = "2011-01-01";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD"); 
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(start_dt);
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String finalString = newFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: change 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'yyyy-MM-DD'. YYYY is not valid

Comment: DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD"); //error
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //correct

Comment: Whlie correct, this Answer is now outdated. The old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
String start_dt = "2011-01-31";

DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date date = (Date) parser.parse(start_dt);

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Prints: 01-31-2011

Answer (score 1):

Tested this code

```
java.text.DateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
java.util.Date newDate = new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(formatter.format(newDate ));
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
String myFormat= "yyyy-MM-dd";
String finalString = "";
try {
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
Date date = (Date) formatter .parse("2015 Oct 09");
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);
finalString= newFormat .format(date );
newDate.setText(finalString);
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2011-01-01" )
         .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ) )
```

## java.time

The other Answers are now outdated. The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## ISO 8601

The input string `2011-01-01` happens to comply with the ISO 8601 standard formats for date-time text. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2011-01-01" ) ;
```

Generate a String in the same format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2011-01-01

## `DateTimeFormatter`

To parse/generate other formats, use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

> 01-01-2011

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Don't forget that is LocalDate needs Android O (API 26) Version to works... The Legacy answer can be conside in this case.

Comment: @lukecross Incorrect. Reread the bullets at the end of my Answer. Also, Gradle Plugin 4 now provides a subset of *java.time* functionality to early Android through a process known as *API desugaring*. So no need to use the terrible legacy date-time classes.

Comment: Library is third part, no support officially by Android Development equip still, and API Desugaring to need migrate, https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support. I can't know whic the version from the all users. Can be 1.7 or 1.8, in 1.7 case, legacy can be usable, mainly for simple cases like a small conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
String date=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2011-01-01"));
```

Where:

```
String date=new SimpleDateFormat("FinalFormat").format(new SimpleDateFormat("InitialFormat").parse("StringDate"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String start_dt = "2011-01-01"; // Input String

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // Existing Pattern
    Date getStartDt = formatter.parse(start_dt); //Returns Date Format according to existing pattern

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");// New Pattern
    String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(getStartDt); // Format given String to new pattern

    System.out.println(formattedDate); //outputs: 01-01-2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, i prefer using this methods:

```
String data = "Date from Register: ";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
// Verify that OS.Version is > API 26 (OREO)
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"); 
// Origin format
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(capitalModels.get(position).getDataServer(), formatter); // Parse String (from server) to LocalDate
            DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
//Output format
            data = "Data de Registro: "+formatter1.format(localDate); // Output
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{ 
//Same resolutions, just use legacy methods to oldest android OS versions.
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd",Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                Date date = format.parse(capitalModels.get(position).getDataServer());
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                data = "Date from Register: "+formatter.format(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```