# Date format issue : Convert from String to Date

Tags: java, date, format

All,

I need to convert the following string "`Tue Jan 01 08:00:00 CET 2013`" to a date object with format "`dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`".

What I have done till now...

```
    String dateStr = "Tue Jan 01 08:00:00 CET 2013";
    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = null;
    try 
    {
       date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);

    } catch ( ParseException e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String formattedDate = "";
    if( date != null ) 
    {
        formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
    }

    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

But this gives me a String as a result and not a date. If I parse the formattedDate String again using the writeFormat then I get the same original date back again i.e. `Tue Jan 01 08:00:00 CET 2013`.

NOTE: Finally, I want to push the date into MySQL DateTime datatype via Java Date object. i.e. String -> Java Date -> MySQL Date Time.

I have searched High/Low on the web and could not find a proper solution. Please help!!!

Thanks and regards,

SG

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to date then format the date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882025/convert-string-to-date-then-format-the-date)

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
date = readFormat.parse(string);
```

And then while saving to MYSQL database...

```
pstmt.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(change.getEndDateTime().getTime()));
```

Thanks for all your responses and apologies for posting duplicate if it is...

Regards,
SG