# Java convert string to java.util.Date object with custom format

Tags: java, date

I have a string like this: `2014-08-20T00:00:00` is possible to convert in a Date (not a string) like this: `20/08/2014` (must be a `java.util.Date` not a String)

Is possible?

Comment: you can use SimpleDateFormat. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to date then format the date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882025/convert-string-to-date-then-format-the-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this:

```
String s ="2014-08-20T00:00:00"; 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(df.parseObject(s));
```